How can I allow `any` only in tests folder with biome?
I have a typescript repository structured in src and tests folder.
I want to configure biome for my project. I want to lint code strictly in src folder, but allowing the any usage in tests folder.
I tried to configure biome.json to allow lint/suspicious/noExplicitAny but that rule is applied also to src, where I want to be strict.
Is there a way to achieve my goal?

Potentially relevant: https://github.com/biomejs/biome/issues/1280

I found a link in the documentation that show how to ignore a particular rule for given paths
https://biomejs.dev/reference/configuration/#overridesitemlinter
In particular, writing biome.json as following, fix my problem.
{
    "$schema": "https://biomejs.dev/schemas/1.9.1/schema.json",
    "vcs": {
        "enabled": false,
        "clientKind": "git",
        "useIgnoreFile": false
    },
    "files": {
        "ignoreUnknown": false,
        "ignore": []
    },
    "formatter": {
        "enabled": true,
        "indentStyle": "tab"
    },
    "organizeImports": {
        "enabled": true
    },
    "linter": {
        "enabled": true,
        "rules": {
            "recommended": true
        }
    },
    "javascript": {
        "formatter": {
            "quoteStyle": "double"
        }
    },
    "overrides": [
        {
          "include": ["tests/**"],
          "linter": {
            "rules": {
              "suspicious": {
                "noExplicitAny": "off"
              }
            }
          }
        }
    ]
}

